# How would I translate this SQL query into a Raven Map/Reduce query?

Tags: ravendb

Following on from my previous question at [When is a groupby query evaluated in RavenDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963777/ravendb-when-is-a-groupby-query-evaluated) I decided to completely restructure the data into a format that is theoretically easier to query on.

Having now created the new data structure, I am struggling to find how to query it.

It took me 30 seconds to write the following SQL query which gives me exactly the results I need:

```
    SELECT        GroupCompanyId, AccountCurrency, AccountName, DATEPART(year, Date) AS Year,
                                 (SELECT        SUM(Debit) AS Expr1
                                   FROM            Transactions AS T2
                                   WHERE        (T1.GroupCompanyId = GroupCompanyId) AND (T1.AccountCurrency = AccountCurrency) AND (T1.AccountName = AccountName) AND (DATEPART(year, 
                                                             Date) < DATEPART(year, T1.Date))) AS OpeningDebits,
                                 (SELECT        SUM(Credit) AS Expr1
                                   FROM            Transactions AS T2
                                   WHERE        (T1.GroupCompanyId = GroupCompanyId) AND (T1.AccountCurrency = AccountCurrency) AND (T1.AccountName = AccountName) AND (DATEPART(year, 
                                                             Date) < DATEPART(year, T1.Date))) AS OpeningCredits, SUM(Debit) AS Db, SUM(Credit) AS Cr
    FROM            Transactions AS T1
    WHERE        (DATEPART(year, Date) = 2011)
    GROUP BY GroupCompanyId, AccountCurrency, AccountName, DATEPART(year, Date)
    ORDER BY GroupCompanyId, AccountCurrency, Year, AccountName
```

So far I have got the Map/Reduce as follows, which from Studio appears to give the correct results - i.e. it breaks down and groups the data by date.

```
public Transactions_ByDailyBalance()
    {
        Map = transactions => from transaction in transactions
                              select new
                                     {
                                         transaction.GroupCompanyId,
                                         transaction.AccountCurrency,
                                         transaction.Account.Category,
                                         transaction.Account.GroupType,
                                         transaction.AccountId,
                                         transaction.AccountName,
                                         transaction.Date,
                                         transaction.Debit,
                                         transaction.Credit,
                                     };
        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by new
                                            {
                                                result.GroupCompanyId,
                                                result.AccountCurrency,
                                                result.Category,
                                                result.GroupType,
                                                result.AccountId,
                                                result.AccountName,
                                                result.Date,
                                            }
                            into g
                            select new
                                   {
                                       GroupCompanyId = g.Select(x=>x.GroupCompanyId).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       AccountCurrency = g.Select(x=>x.AccountCurrency).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       Category=g.Select(x=>x.Category).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       GroupType=g.Select(x=>x.GroupType).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       AccountId = g.Select(x=>x.AccountId).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       AccountName=g.Select(x=>x.AccountName).FirstOrDefault(),                                           
                                       Date=g.Select(x=>x.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       Debit=g.Sum(x=>x.Debit),
                                       Credit=g.Sum(x=>x.Credit)
                                   };

        Index(x=>x.GroupCompanyId,FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(x=>x.AccountCurrency,FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(x=>x.Category,FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(x=>x.AccountId,FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(x=>x.AccountName,FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(x=>x.Date,FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

However, I can't work out how to query the data at one go.
I need the opening balance as well as the period balance, so I ended up writing this query which takes as a parameter the account. Following on from Oren's comments to my previous question, that I was mixing Linq with Lucene query, having rewritten the query, I've basically ended up again with a mixed query.

Even though I am showing in the SQL query above that I am filtering by year, in fact I need to be able to determine the current balance from any day.

```
     private LedgerBalanceDto GetAccountBalance(BaseAccountCode account, DateTime periodFrom, DateTime periodTo, string queryName)
    {
        using (var session = MvcApplication.RavenSession)
        {
            var query = session.Query<Transactions_ByDailyBalance.Result, Transactions_ByDailyBalance>()
                .Where(c=>c.AccountId==account.Id && c.Date>=periodFrom && c.Date<=periodTo)
                .OrderBy(c=>c.Date)
                .ToList();

            var debits = query.Sum(c => c.Debit);
            var credits = query.Sum(c => c.Credit);

            var ledgerBalanceDto = new LedgerBalanceDto
                                   {
                                       Account = account,
                                       Credits = credits,
                                       Debits = debits,
                                       Currency = account.Currency,
                                       CurrencySymbol = account.CurrencySymbol,
                                       Name = queryName,
                                       PeriodFrom = periodFrom,
                                       PeriodTo = periodTo
                                   };

            return ledgerBalanceDto;
        }
    }
```

Required result:

```
    GroupCompanyId  AccountCurrency AccountName Year    OpeningDebits   OpeningCredits  Db  Cr
    Groupcompanies-2    EUR Customer 1  2011    148584.2393 125869.91   10297.6891  28023.98
    Groupcompanies-2    EUR Customer 2  2011    236818.0054 233671.55   50959.85    54323.38
    Groupcompanies-2    USD Customer 3  2011    69426.11761 23516.3776  10626.75    0
    Groupcompanies-2    USD Customer 4  2011    530587.9223 474960.51   97463.544   131497.16
    Groupcompanies-2    USD Customer 5  2011    29542.391   28850.19    4023.688    4231.388
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Jeremy

In answer to the comment

I basically ended up doing pretty much the same thing. Actually, I wrote an index that does it in only two hits - once for the opening balance and again for the period balance. This is almost instantaneous for grouping by the account name, category etc.

However my problem now is getting a daily running balance for the individual account. If I bring down all the data for the account and the period, its not a problem - I can sum the balance on the client, however, when the data is paged, and the debits and credits are grouped by Date and Id, the paging cuts across the date, so the opening/closing balance is not correct.

```
Page 1

Opening balance until 26/7/12 = 0

25/7/12    Acct1       Db 100       Cr 0     Bal  +100    Runn Bal +100
26/7/12    Acct1       Db 100       Cr 0     Bal  +100    Runn Bal +200
26/7/12    Acct1       Db 200       Cr 0     Bal  +200    Runn Bal +400

Closing balance until 26/7/12 = +400

Page 2
Opening balance until 26/7/12 = +450 (this is wrong - it should be the balance at the end of Page 1, but it is the balance until the 26/7/12 - i.e. includes the first item on Page 2)
26/7/12    Acct1       Db 50        Cr 0     Bal  +50     Runn Bal +500 (should be +450)
27/7/12    Acct1       Db 60        Cr 0     Bal  +60     Runn Bal +560 (should be +510)
```

I just can't think up an algorithm to handle this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is a problem I have also faced recently with RavenDb when I needed to retrieve rolling balances as at any imaginable date. I never found a way of doing this all in one go but I managed reduce the amount of documents that I needed to pull back in order to calculate the rolling balance.

I did this by writing multiple map reduce indexes that summed up the value of transactions within specific periods:

1. My First Summed up the value of all transactions grouped at the year level
2. My Second index Summed up the value of all transactions at the Day level

So if someone wanted their account balance As At 1st June 2012 I would:

1. Use the Year level Map-reduce index to get the Value of transactions for years up to 2012 and summed them together (so if transactions started being captured in 2009 I should be pulling back 3 documents)
2. Use the Day level Map-reduce index to get all documents from the start of the year and the 1st of June

I then Added the Day totals to the year totals for my final rolling balance (I could have also had a monthly map reduce as well but didn't bother).

Anyway not as quick as in SQL but it was the best alternative I could come up with to avoid bringing back every single transaction